# Delete messages on advertising channel

Tags: discord, discord.py

I need delete messages on advertising channel, but bot ignore command. Maybe I need some commands or request patch to API discord.py?
Code:

```
#intents is all btw.
@client.command()
async def purge(ctx, *, a):
    a = int(a) + 1
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = a)
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Do you by any chance have an `on_message` event?

Comment: No no, everything in bot is ok, but I can't only delete messages on advertising channel. On normal channel bot can delete

Comment: Make sure the bot has permission to delete messages on that channel.

Comment: But bot have administrator permission, he have everything

Comment: Is there any error that is coming from the console because the code ran fine for me?

Comment: Oh. Today bot delete messages. I think, discord have some problems, for eg. embed